# Magento 2 WYSIWYG field in custom admin form

Tags: adminform, magento2.3.1, wysiwyg, ui-form, custom-field

I'm trying to add some fiels dynamically with Ui interface in a custom admin form.

in order_ticket_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
---
    <fieldset name="message" class="Bileamara\SalesOrderGrid\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset\Ticket\Message">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add Message in Every Language</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and Bileamara\SalesOrderGrid\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset\Ticket\Message

```
<?php  
namespace Bileamara\SalesOrderGrid\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset\Ticket;


use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;  
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentInterface;  
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\FieldFactory;  
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset as BaseFieldset;
use Magento\Store\Model\System\Store as SystemStore;
use Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config as WysiwygConfig;

class Message extends BaseFieldset  
{
    /**
     * @var FieldFactory
     */
    private $fieldFactory;

    protected $systemStore;

    public function __construct(
        WysiwygConfig $wysiwygConfig,
        SystemStore $systemStore,
        ContextInterface $context,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = [],
        FieldFactory $fieldFactory)
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $components, $data);
        $this->_wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;
        $this->systemStore = $systemStore;
        $this->fieldFactory = $fieldFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Get components
     *
     * @return UiComponentInterface[]
     */
    public function getChildComponents()
    {   
        $wysiwygConfig = $this->_wysiwygConfig->getConfig([
                                                        'hidden' => 0
                                                        ]);

        $storeCollection = $this->systemStore->getStoreCollection();
        foreach ($storeCollection as $store) {          
            $fields['message_'.$store->getCode()] = [
            'formElement' => 'wysiwyg',
            'label' => $store->getName(),
            'wysiwyg' => true,
            'required' => true,
            'config' => $wysiwygConfig,
            ];
        }
        foreach ($fields as $name => $fieldConfig) {
            $fieldInstance = $this->fieldFactory->create();
            $fieldInstance->setData(
                [
                    'config' => $fieldConfig,
                    'name' => $name,
                ]
            );

            $fieldInstance->prepare();
            $this->addComponent($name, $fieldInstance);
        }

        return parent::getChildComponents();
    }
}
```

Now I got the fields
[image]

but:

- editor is hidden and should be visible
- label is missing
- there is no space betwin fields

I need to set field id different from name, somting like

- id => message_en
- name => message[en]

because i need message result in an array.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to add `'template' => 'ui/form/field'` in field configuration so now the code is

```
public function getChildComponents()
{
    $stores = $this->storeManager->getStores();

    uasort(
        $stores,
        function (\Magento\Store\Model\Store $storeA, \Magento\Store\Model\Store $storeB) {
            return $storeA->getSortOrder() <=> $storeB->getSortOrder();
        }    
    );

    foreach ($stores as $store) {   
        $fields['message_'.$store->getCode()] = [
        'formElement' => 'wysiwyg',
        'label' => $store->getName().'_'.$store->getSortOrder(),
        'wysiwyg' => true,
        'wysiwygConfigData' => [
                                'hidden' => false,
                                'add_widgets' => false, 
                                'add_variables' => false,
                                ],
        'validation' => ['required-entry' => true],
        'template' => 'ui/form/field'
        ];
    }
    foreach ($fields as $name => $fieldConfig) {
        $fieldInstance = $this->fieldFactory->create();
        $fieldInstance->setData(
            [
                'config' => $fieldConfig,
                'name' => $name,
            ]
        );

        $fieldInstance->prepare();
        $this->addComponent($name, $fieldInstance);
    }

    return parent::getChildComponents();
}
```

Still wonder if there is any chance to group fields like address field in order form, something like message[en]

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code**.....its work for me for creating editor in custom  ui form

```
<field name="content" sortOrder="10" formElement="wysiwyg" template="ui/form/field">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="is_pagebuilder_enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="height" xsi:type="string">200px</item>
                    <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Contents</label>
            <dataScope>content</dataScope>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <wysiwyg>
                <settings>
                    <rows>5</rows>
                    <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
                </settings>
            </wysiwyg>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```